# What ports does the Samba client require?

Tags: samba

Since an Ubuntu machine needs an smb client to access a smb server, it would have to establish a connection to the server.

What ports does the client open to establish the connection?

Do those ports continue to listen for incoming connections once the connection to the smb server ends?

Note: I am asking about the ports used by a smb client, not a smb server.

Comment: To discover what ports a given service uses, you can use `firewall-config` to get a pretty big list of default configurations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is from https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_Port_Usage

> Identify on which ports and interfaces Samba is listening
>
> You can use `netstat` to identify which ports Samba and related
>   daemons are listening on and on which IPs:
>
> ```
> # netstat -tulpn | egrep "samba|smbd|nmbd|winbind" The following is a snippet of an example output:
>
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:139               0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      43270/smbd           tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:139     
> 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      43270/smbd           tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:88                 0.0.0.0:*
> ```
>
> LISTEN      43273/samba          tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:88
>       0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      43273/samba          tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:445               0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      43270/smbd           tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:445
>       0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      43270/smbd
>
> The above example shows, that the services are listening on
>   `localhost` (127.0.0.1) and the interface with IP 10.0.0.1 - each on
>   the listed ports (139, 88, 445,...).
>
> Port usage when Samba runs as an Active Directory Domain Controller
>
> ```
> Service   Port    protocol
>
> DNS   53  tcp/udp
>
> Kerberos  88  tcp/udp
>
> End Point Mapper (DCE/RPC Locator Service)    135 tcp
>
> NetBIOS Name Service  137 udp
>
> NetBIOS Datagram  138 udp
>
> NetBIOS Session   139 tcp
>
> LDAP  389 tcp/udp
>
> SMB over TCP  445 tcp
>
> Kerberos kpasswd  464 tcp/udp
>
> LDAPS (only if "tls enabled = yes")   636 tcp
>
> Dynamic RPC Ports*    1024-5000   tcp
>
> Global Cataloge   3268    tcp
>
> Global Cataloge SSL (only if "tls enabled = yes") 3269    tcp
>
> Multicast DNS 5353    tcp/udp
> ```
>
> - Samba, like Windows, supports dynamic RPC services. The range starts at 1024. If something occupies this port for some reason, it will be a
>     different port (literally walked up from 1024). Remember, that there
>     can be other ports too, which are related to your Samba installation
>     but not provided from Samba itself, like if you run a NTP server for
>     time synchronisation as well.
>
> Port usage when Samba runs as an NT4 Primary Domain Controller
>
> ```
> Service   Port    protocol
>
> End Point Mapper (DCE/RPC Locator Service)    135 tcp
>
> NetBIOS Name Service  137 udp
>
> NetBIOS Datagram  138 udp
>
> NetBIOS Session   139 tcp
>
> SMB over TCP  445 tcp
> ```
>
> Port usage when Samba runs as a Member Server
>
> ```
> Service   Port    protocol
>
> End Point Mapper (DCE/RPC Locator Service)    135 tcp
>
> NetBIOS Name Service  137 udp
>
> NetBIOS Datagram  138 udp
>
> NetBIOS Session   139 tcp
>
> SMB over TCP  445 tcp
> ```

Comment: A ton more information than what I asked for! I was looking for the last part (Samba client as a member server). Thank you!

Comment: Also keep in mind that your Samba client will use any of these ports depending on the server it's connecting to, so more than just the last part of the answer is applicable if you want a full answer.