# How do I find out which ports I need to open in my firewall to get Samba working?

Tags: samba, firewall, ufw

I want to be able to access a shared folder on a windows 8 computer from my Linux computer. Everything works fine when Ufw is turned off, but as soon as I enable the firewall it won't work.

How do I find out which ports I need to open in Ufw to get it to work?

Please note that yes, there are many posts about how to solve this problem by opening ports and which those ports are, but my question is how I can find out which ports to open.

Comment: I vote to close this because you will need to find out on your Windows Computer and not on Ubuntu.

Comment: Is that so? How about looking in the log of ufw?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What ports does the Samba client require?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649969/what-ports-does-the-samba-client-require)

Comment: Well, maybe it should but when I run `sudo netstat -tulpn | egrep "samba|smbd|nmbd|winbind"` I don't get any output :(

Comment: Better yet, install `gufw` as it gives you a GUI interface for the `ufw` and allows you to choose apps that have all the ports pre-chosen.  `sudo apt install gufw`

Answer (score 0):

this ports tcp 445
if you plan to use netbios/name resolution this ports: 137 138 udp 137 139 tcp

Greethings bernd

Comment: Thanks for your post, but opening the ports above doesn't help ...